# Binomial conditional on Poisson

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

I have a binomial $CNT\sim\mathcal{B}(n,p)$, and a poisson $P\sim \mathcal{P}(\lambda)$.

Now I'm looking at $CNT$ *conditional* on $P$:

What’s the expected value, $E(B|P)$?  What is the variance $Var(B|P)$?  What is the covariance $Cov(B,P)$?  Are there closed forms, or must we always go through the sums?

After feedback in the comments, here's what I have.  Going through the sums:

$$
E(\textbf{CNT}|A^*) = \sum_{w=0}^{w^*} \sum_{v=-w}^{+w} vP(\text{CNT}=v|A^*=w) P(A^*=w)
$$
$$
= \sum_{w=0}^{w^*} \sum_{k=0}^{w} (2k-w) P(\text{CNT}=(2k-w)|A^*=w) P(A^*=w)
$$

$$
=\sum_{w=0}^{w^*} \sum_{k=0}^{w} (2k-w) \binom{w}{k} p^{k} (1-p)^{w-k} P(A^*=w)
$$

where $w^* = 4\lambda$, $\text{CNT} \sim{B}(w,p)$, and $A^*\sim{P}(\lambda)$.

This, and the corresponding for variance, yields correct numerical values.  What I wonder is whether or not there are closed forms for $E(CNT|A^*)$, $Var(CNT|A^*)$, and $Cov(CNT,A^*)$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: What is the relationship between $B$ and $P$?

Comment: Use the laws of total expectation and variance (after clarifying how $B$ depends on $P$.)

Comment: I'm updating the question after your feedback.  Many many thanks!

Comment: @herbsteinberg $B$ gives the values of a (potentially asymmetric) Drunkard's walk/Gambler's ruin after the $w$-th step.  $P$, with $\lambda=10.71$, is the probability that we have just arrived at the $w$-th step.  (This is why $v=2k-w$.)